# Reading sms inbox is not working in android?

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am using cordova phonegap 2.1.0

I have downloaded the code from:
[Phone Gap SMS Read Extension](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMS%20inbox_sent%20access)

Then i have modified the code according to new cordova library

Modified Smsread.js

```
var SMSReader = function () {};

SMSReader.prototype.getInbox = function(params, success, fail) {
    return cordova.exec(function (args) {
    success(args);
}, function(args) {
    fail(args);
}, 'SMSReader', 'inbox', [params]);
};

SMSReader.prototype.getSent = function(params, success, fail) {
return cordova.exec(function (args) {
    success(args);
}, function(args) {
    fail(args);
}, 'SMSReader', 'sent', [params]);};
if (!window.plugins) {
window.plugins = {};
}
 if (!window.plugins.SMSReader) {
window.plugins.SMSReader = new SMSReader();
}
//cordova.addConstructor(function () {
//    cordova.addPlugin("SMSReader", new SMSReader());
//    PluginManager.addService("SMSReader", "com.example.sample2");
//});
```

Modified SMSReader.java

```
package com.example.sample2;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



public class SMSReader extends Plugin {

Context ctx;
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {
    Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Plugin Called");
    PluginResult result = null;
    JSONObject messages = new JSONObject();
    if (action.equals("inbox")) {
        try {
            Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "TRY Called");
            messages = readSMS("inbox");
            Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Returning " + messages.toString());
            result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, messages);
        } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
            Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Got JSON Exception "+ jsonEx.getMessage());
            result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
    else if(action.equals("sent")){
         try {
            messages = readSMS("sent");
            Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Returning " + messages.toString());
            result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, messages);
        } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
            Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Got JSON Exception "+ jsonEx.getMessage());
            result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
    else {
        result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Invalid action : "+action+" passed");
    }
    return result;
}


//Read messages from inbox/or sent box.
private JSONObject readSMS(String folder) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("");
    if(folder.equals("inbox")){
        uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Inbox Called");
    }
    else if(folder.equals("sent")){
            uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
            Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "Sent Called");
    }
    Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "content Before");
   // Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "content Called");
    JSONArray smsList = new JSONArray();
    data.put("messages", smsList);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("SMSReadPlugin", "cursor Called");
      JSONObject sms = new JSONObject();
        sms.put("number",cur.getString(2));
        sms.put("text",cur.getString(11));

        String name = getContact(cur.getString(2));
        if(!name.equals("")){
            sms.put("name",name);
        }
        smsList.put(sms);
    }
    return data;
}

private String getContact(String number){
    Cursor cur = this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    String returnName= "";
    if(cur.getCount() > 0){
        while(cur.moveToNext()){
              String id =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
              Log.d("Contact","ID:" + id );
              String name =  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
               Log.d("Contact","name:" + name);
              if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                  Cursor pcur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=?",new String[]{number},null);
                  int numindex = pcur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
                  if(pcur.moveToFirst()){
                      String dbNum = pcur.getString(numindex);
                      if(dbNum.equals(number)){
                       returnName = name;
                      Log.d("number","number:" + dbNum);
                      }
                      else {
                          Log.d("number","numbers dont match!");
                      }
                  }
                  else {
                      Log.d("number", "no result");
                  }

              }
                else {
                   Log.d("number", "No Number");
              }
        }
    }
    return returnName;
}

private ContentResolver getContentResolver(){
    return ctx.getContentResolver();
 }
```

}

Still i am not able to get the result. kindly help.

Comment: any error you get while executing it?